# Sonar client org.sonar.wsclient.base.HttpException: Error 407

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonar client API in order to display the code smells in a personalized version. But I am getting the above error while doing so? before I used to get the output.

```
public class ab{
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:9001";
    String login = "admin";
    String password = "admin";

    SonarClient client = SonarClient.builder()
              .url(url)
              .login(login)
              .password(password)
              .build();

    IssueQuery query = IssueQuery.create();
    query.rules("Major","Minor","Critical");
    IssueClient issueClient = client.issueClient();
    Issues issues = issueClient.find(query);
    List<Issue> issueList = issues.list();

    for (int i = 0; i < issueList.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(issueList.get(i).projectKey() + " " +
                          issueList.get(i).componentKey() + " " +
                          issueList.get(i).line() + " " +
                          issueList.get(i).ruleKey() + " " +
                          issueList.get(i).severity() + " " +
                          issueList.get(i).message());
     }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Http Error 407` is thrown when the resource you are trying to access needs *Proxy Authentication*. But as you are accessing the service over *127.0.0.1*, which indicates it is your local system, you shouldn't get `407` error. Try adding the entry to your hosts file (Under *YOUR_WINDOWS_FOLDER\System32\drivers\etc*) as

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Alternatively, have you tried accessing the URL over `localhost` as below?

> http://localhost:9001

And finally, if the sonarqube is hosted on a separate server, you could set the proxy authentication as below just before invoking the service.

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.Proxy;
.
.
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("PROXY_SERVER", 80));
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("PROXY_USERNAME", "PROXY_PASSWORD".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```